# System App not updating automatically

Tags: android

We have developed an app that is distributed in google play as well as embedded as system-app in some devices. The system-app does not update automatically to the latest version that is present on google play. There is no difference in the permissions required in both apps. Any idea why this should happen?

Comment: This can be happen only if both apks signed with different certificate. If your system application is not signed by same certificate, which apk on play store is signed, Google Play will treat it as different application and will not notify for update.

Comment: Does it have the same package name in both the pre-install and play store versions? Also, did you add new permissions (if new permissions are added, the user must upgrade manually to accept the new permissions)?

Comment: Actually given your comment below that manual upgrades work, you almost certainly added a permission.  There's no way around that, its a security issue (otherwise you could install with no permissions, then add everything in an update).

Comment: Thanks Gabe, we rechecked the Manifest files of both apps multiple times after your suggestion. Here's the difference: 1. The system app manifest has 1 additional permission which is not present in the google play app. 2. The system app has android:sharedUserId="some.package" which the google play app does not have. Any clue what's happening?